# Internal 500 Error - Node.js - express-session

Tags: node.js, express, express-session, http-status-code-500

For some reason when I compile my server, I get a 500 error on all of the paths:

```
info: [c:\Users\PC\WebstormProjects\practice\app.js] Express is listening on port: 3000
GET / 304 13.601 ms - -
GET /css/bootstrap.css 500 5.725 ms - 1028
GET /js/jquery.js 500 3.748 ms - 1028
GET /js/bootstrap.js 500 4.097 ms - 1028
GET /favicon.ico 500 1.889 ms - 1028
```

The only thing I've been playing around is 'express-sessions'. I've got some tutorials that I'm following but they are all for older express version and so I have to re-write some stuff and I haven't even done much but initialized the session.

The only thing changed in my app.js:

```
var session = require('express-session');

var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

app.use(session({
    genid: function(req) {
        return genuuid();// use UUIDs for session IDs
    },
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    cookie: {
        maxAge: null
    },
    proxy: true,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

to the top of your server file. Right now, "app" is undefined which is probably causing the 500 code (it means internal server error).

You also probably want to specify something for your server to do when it receives a request by adding an

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) { ... } );
```

since otherwise your server probably won't serve anything.

Comment: Well, I am not that kind of beginner :) The code I provided is just a snippet from my app.js. The entire file is probably too big to post here. This snippet is the only change I've made since my last successful configuration.